# Как автоматически сортировать строки в Excel?

Tags: vba, сортировка, excel

Есть таблица

[image]

Необходимо сделать автоматическую сортировку строк по столбцу "Общее" в порядке убывания и делаю я это так:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
[E3].CurrentRegion.Sort [E3], xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

В итоге получаю то что хотел:

[image]

Но это работаю только в том случае, если значения поля "Общее" (11 и 14) вставлены вручную, но если там стоит формула авто-суммы, то ничего не происходит. 
Что нужно сделать, чтобы сортировка происходила при значениях, полученные в результате авто-сумму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не рассматривать target. С другой стороны, тогда будет сортировать и при изменениях, которые не приводят к изменениям в е. Для того, чтобы проверять наличие изменений, вы можете сохранить значения столбца е в массив (m_values = rng.value, где rng - столбец), и при каждом изменении проверять его.

Comment: я не силен в VBA, не мог ли бы вы показать более готовое решение?

Comment: Тогда вам проще написать в вашем решении C:E вместо E:E.

Answer (score 1):

Событие Worksheet_Change не реагирует на пересчет формул.

Если диапазоны, на которые ссылаются формулы, находятся далеко от таблицы (или на других листах) и их нельзя включить в проверяемый диапазон *Target*, можно использовать событие пересчета листа:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        [E2].CurrentRegion.Sort [E2], xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*Application.EnableEvents* - чтобы избежать зацикливания, на время сортировки отключаем события листа.

Сортировка будет происходить при пересчете формул. Чтобы пересчет происходил и при ручном изменении данных, в произвольную ячейку нужно добавить формулу с летучей функцией (летучая - пересчитывается при любом изменении на листе), например:

```
=СЕГОДНЯ()
```

Недостаток данного решения - сортировка включается при любом изменении на листе.

Если пересчет формул происходит не часто, можно параллельно с *Worksheet_Change* использовать событие активации листа - *Worksheet_Activate*